# Integration of fraction of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry

my problem consist of several trigonometric functions in a fraction and that whole thing should get integrated:
$$
\int \frac{(\operatorname{tg} x + \operatorname{cotg} x )^2}{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x} dx
$$

The only thing I can do is to rewrite it to a form $\int \frac{\operatorname{tg}^2 x + 2 + \operatorname{cotg}^2 x}{(\sin x + \cos x)(\sin x - \cos x)} dx$ which is leading me to partial fraction and/or substitution, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using 
\begin{align}
\tan(x) + cotan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} + \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)} = \frac{\cos^{2}(x) + \sin^{2}(x)}{\sin(x) \cos(x)} = \frac{1}{\cos(x) \sin(x)}
\end{align}
and $\cos^{2}(x) - \sin^{2}(x) = \cos(2x)$ then the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int \frac{(\tan(x) + cotan(x) )^2}{\sin^2 x - \cos^2 x} dx
\end{align}
becomes
\begin{align}
I &= - \int \frac{4 \, dx}{(\sin(2x))^{2} \cos(2x)} \\
&= 2 \ln\left( \frac{\cos(x) - \sin(x)}{\cos(x) + \sin(x)} \right) + \frac{2}{\sin(2x)} + c_{0}
\end{align}
where Wolfram Alpha was used to evaluate the last integral

Answer (score 0):

Now the integral to simplifies to
$$\int\frac{-4}{\sin^2 2x\cos 2x}dx$$ as from above. Now I will show you how to get the Wolfram result.
$$\int\frac{-4}{\sin^2 2x\cos 2x}dx=\int\frac{-4\cos 2x}{\sin^2 2x\cos^2 2x}dx=\int\frac{-4\cos 2x}{\sin^2 2x(1-\sin^2 2x)}dx.$$
Next use the substitution $u=\sin 2x$ which gives $dx=2\cos2x dx$. Substituting and using partial fractions, we have
\begin{array}
$\displaystyle\int\frac{-2}{u^2(1-u^2)}du &=&\displaystyle\int\bigg(\frac{-2}{u^2}-\frac{1}{1-u}-\frac{1}{1+u}\bigg)du\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{2}{u}+\ln|1-u|-\ln|1+u|+c\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{2}{\sin 2x}+\ln\bigg|\frac{1-\sin 2x}{1+\sin 2x}\bigg|+c\\
&=&\displaystyle\frac{2}{\sin 2x}+\ln\bigg|\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)^2 }{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}\bigg|+c\\
\end{array}

since $1+\sin 2x=(\cos x+\sin x)^2$ and $1-\sin 2x=(\cos x-\sin x)^2$, from which the Wolfram results follows.